# Need client-side time to mirror server-side time

Tags: node.js, time

I need client-side time to mirror server-side time. Are there any best practices around this?

I'm not sure how exactly I would go about making sure the two match.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that you could really get them to match without physically changing the server time to match but that could cause havoc since everyone's time is slightly different.

Comment: @Nomad101  Well I was thinking you could just figure out the delta, keep it in memory on the client and always adjust. Just need to figure out a way to get an accurate delta.

Comment: Take a look at @Daniels solution then it seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

[Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) has an [algorithm for synchronizing time](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ALGO-BASIC-SYNC) between machines while accounting for network latency.

If you were to implement such an algorithm with AJAX or (even better) websockets, then you would end up with a value holding the differential between local machine time and server time.

Any time you did a time calculation on the client side, you could utilize that time differential value to adjust the output to be reasonably close to server time.  It's never going to be exact, but you could probably get within 100 milliseconds on most connections.

Comment: Yes, this is along the lines of what I was thinking and I am using websockets. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends upon what you mean, as your phrasing doesn't really give enough info to know *why* you want the time to be the same across the different machines..

If you mean "*I want all of the system clocks to be set to the very same time*" then you need to search for stuff related to Network Time Protocol.  Google can give you [links to intro materials](https://www.google.com/search?q=ntp+network+time+protocol) and there is also an [overview of NTP on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228089/how-does-the-network-time-protocol-work).  But that's not a Node.js or programming problem...and the answers can be very operating system specific...and if you don't own all of the clients then you are out of luck

If you mean "*I want all events to happen at the same time on all clients even if the system clocks are different*" then there is already [a question here that has all of these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585910/sync-js-time-between-multiple-devices).

Good luck.